# Can I implement prefetching of URIs after a page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, prefetch

I run a small search engine with an autocompleting search box.

I would love to prefetch a user's first suggested search result (after entering some characters into the search box on the homepage) but everything I am reading states that prefetch `link` tags must be hardcoded into the HTML or at least available on page load (if they were generated dynamically via javscript, for example).

Is it at all possible to initiate a browser's prefetch function AFTER page load? Because obviously I cannot guess what a user will search for in the search box.

Comment: what does search have to do with `<link>` tags? Question is really confusing. How does your `search` work?

Comment: @charlietfl I am referring to my homepage pre-fetching search result pages after the homepage has loaded but before the user has determined which suggested search result to go with yet.

Comment: None of this question makes much sense

Comment: @charlietfl my question is "Can I implement prefetching of URIs after a page has loaded?" - what do you not understand? Nevermind trying to understand my personal use case. I'm just trying to initiate prefetching of certain URIs after a page has loaded, as opposed to prefetching them on load with `link` tags.